# DBCC TempDB Space Usage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dbcc-checkdb

We are using `DBCC CHECKDB` on a VLDB 1TB in size.  Previously when on our 2008 platform the check ran successfully on a drive that was 150GB in size for TempDB, but since moving to SQL 2012 and AlwaysOn the check is now running out of space on a 200GB drive.

The `DBCC CHECKDB with ESTIMATEONLY` is returning a value of 1, so I think we are suffering from what some have said is a bug in that command.

Does `CHECKDB` work differently between SQL versions?

**P.S.** I know a work around is to break up the check into batches but we are wanting to know why this has become an issue now.

Comment: As far as I know, ESTIMATEONLY is bugged. Some says it was fixed in 2012 version with sp2, some say no. Was 2008 version r2? Has database in SQL 2012 heavy activity?

Comment: At the time the DBCC runs theres not a lot else going on no.

Comment: What is the waittype when you are running CHECKDB ? Are you having any blobs or non-clustered indexes on computed columns or sparse columns in your database ?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I will check out what columns there are in our largest table.